# Difference between bean id and Reference type

Tags: java, spring

What's a difference between `Bean ID` and `reference type` ?

I'm confused that both are pointing to object only. Please correct me

Comment: you can have multiple beans of the same reference type but they each need to have different ids

Comment: In we flatens down, both are reference types only, Correct ? Its just a different way of doing it in Spring framework. Correct ?

Comment: You can get a bean via its id / name `applicationContext.getBean("someName")` or via its type / class `applicationContext.getBean(SomeService.class)`. Not sure what you mean with: *In we flatens down, both are reference types only*, sorry

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, beans can “access” to each other by specify the bean references in the same or different bean configuration file.

If you are referring to a bean in different XML file, you can reference it with a ‘ref‘ tag, ‘bean‘ attribute.

Actually, the ‘ref’ tag can access to a bean either in same or different XML files, however, for the project readability, you should use the ‘local’ attribute if you reference to a bean which declared in the same XML file.